# How to not return the same node in different columns in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to not return the same node twice in this query in separate columns

```
START n=node:nodes(customer = 'c2')
MATCH n-[:OWNS]->owned-[:CROSS_SELL|UP_SELL]->sell
RETURN distinct n.customer,owned.product,sell.product
```

Customer C2 owns products P1 and P2.  Product P2 and P3 can be cross sold from product P1.  Product P3 can be also be up sold from product P2.

The query correctly returns

```
C2 P1 P3
C2 P2 P3
C2 P1 P2
```

Since the customer already owns P2, I do not want the last record in the result.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

simply add a condition where you filter up on relationship between C2 and P2

```
START n=node:nodes(customer = 'c2')
MATCH n-[:OWNS]->owned-[:CROSS_SELL|UP_SELL]->sell
WHERE not(n-[:OWNS]-sell)
RETURN distinct n.customer,owned.product,sell.product
```

Comment: +1, but you probably should put an arrow in your predicate `not(n-[:OWNS]->sell)` (not that it would ever be the other way).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested to verify that this works, but it seems logically correct:

```
START n=node:nodes(customer = 'c2')
MATCH n-[:OWNS]->owned-[:CROSS_SELL|UP_SELL]->sell,
      alreadyOwns = n-[:OWNS]->sell
WHERE COUNT(alreadyOwns) = 0
RETURN distinct n.customer,owned.product,sell.product
```

The idea is basically to try and find a direct match from the start node to the cross/up-sold item and if a path is found then don't include it.